# Как изменить стиль через CSS?

Tags: css

Допустим, есть код:

CSS:

```
#a1 {
   color:red;
}

#a1:hover {
   color:green;
}

#a2 {
   color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a1">1
   <div id="a2">2</div>
</div>
```

Можно как то реализовать что бы :hover также изменял стиль a2?

Comment: #a1:hover #a2 { }

Comment: Ответ сверху верный. Рекомендую вам привязывать стили к классам, а не к идентификаторам.

Comment: @mJeevas, Ну не совсем. ID - очень полезное свойство, но из-за особенности применения, его нельзя часто использовать, поэтому чаще классы юзают. Но ID куда быстрее находится, уникален и просто няш-мяш :)

Comment: А как правильней для стиля использовать class или id к примеру с таким кодом:
.div3:hover {
 border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px;
 padding:4px 6px 4px 7px;
 border-left: 1px #E0E0E0 solid;
 border-top: 1px #E0E0E0 solid;
 border-right: 1px #E0E0E0 solid;
 background-color: #096;
 color:#C33;
 transition: 0.1s;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

Answer (score 1):

Легко:
`a1:hover a2{%styleRule%}`.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!

Comment: А если бы еще был стиль a3? Можно сразу несколько привязать?

Comment: @Юрий9090, скажем так: `:hover` ставишь около элемента, который должен реагировать на наведение, а последним элементом должен быть тот, кто меняется.  Например: `my .super:hover .puper .element{}` - ищет тэг `my`, в нём ищет все классы `.super`, внутри них класс `.puper` и ещё внутри `.element`. Стили применится только при наведении на любой `.super` к любому `.element`.

Comment: я вот так делал:
my #ps:hover #wwww #www{
 background-color:#096;
 color: #FFF;
}

Не хочет работать...

Но как было так:

#ps:hover #www{
 background-color:#096;
 color: #FFF;
}

#ps:hover #wwww{
 background-color:#096;
 color: #FFF;
}

То работало норм)

Comment: @Юрий9090, Старик, запомни - `id` может быть только ОДИН в DOOM. Поэтому эта конструкция бессмысленна, ибо можно так: `#ps:hover #www`.